# properly escape URL slashes in regex

Tags: php, regex

I need help escaping slashes in a pattern which searches a URL path. I'm trying to check if a path contains any numbers in the path after `/orders/` like this:

```
$str = '/admin/store/orders/20284?width...';

if ( preg_match ( '/orders/([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

However, I am not able to escape the slashes properly. Can anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: Try `'\/orders\/([0-9]+)\/'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping is done with backslashes (`\/`). But the slash character to delimit regular expressions can be any character:

```
if ( preg_match ( '~orders/([0-9]+)~', $str, $matches ) )
```

Will work without escaping.

Comment: I flip-flop between `#` and `|` as I find the latter easier to read, but it doesn't work if you've got an alternate search `|` in your pattern.

Comment: @miken32: indeed, that's why using `|` as delimiter isn't a good choice. Note that `#` has a special meaning too if you use the x modifier or in the sequence `(?#comment)`. Most of the time, I use `~` (better choice than `/`)

Comment: Delimiter has been changed by popular request. Thanks for the feedback!